# Xamarin: Refactoring to use async/await

Tags: c#, ios, asynchronous, xamarin.ios, xamarin

What's the best way to refactor this code to use async/await? This code snippet is from the [Xamarin Field Services Sample App](https://github.com/xamarin/prebuilt-apps/blob/master/FieldService/FieldService.iOS)

Data provider interface for ViewModels

```
public interface ILoginService {
            Task<bool> LoginAsync (string username, string password, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));
    }
```

Interface implementation for login. Here just sleeping to fake network call...

```cs
public class LoginService : ILoginService {    
   public Task<bool> LoginAsync (string username, string password, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken)) {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew (() => {
                Thread.Sleep (1000);
                return true;
            }, cancellationToken);
        }
}
```

Button click handler

```cs
partial void Login () {
        //some ui related code
        loginViewModel
            .LoginAsync ()
            .ContinueWith (_ => 
                BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => {
                    //go to different view
                }));
    }
```

What's the best way to refactor this code to use async/await?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
partial async void Login () 
{
    //some ui related code
    await loginViewModel.LoginAsync ();
     //go to different view
}
```

You don't need to switch threads as `await` captures the current `SynchroniztionContext` and post the remainder of the method as a continuation on that same context. For UI thread, this essentially means that the `go to different view` section will be executing on the UI thrad as well.

You probably should check the result of the `LoginAsync` operation as well

```
private async void Login () 
{
    //some ui related code
    if(await loginViewModel.LoginAsync())
    {
        //go to different view
    }
    else
    {
       // login failed
    }
}
```

I wouldn't refactor this any further as it is quite simple.

Comment: Otherwise would be good but the partial method is going to be an issue as the method needs to be marked with async.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Any opportunity to refactor the LoginService implementation?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about refactoring it any further. Usually you provide an implementation without a `CancellationToken` but you have effectively achieved that with the `deafult` value.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to refactor delay into anything meaningful but it would simply be like this:

```
public class LoginService : ILoginService 
{    
    public async Task<bool> LoginAsync (string username, string password, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken)) 
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000), cancellationToken);
        return true;
    }
}
```

The delay would be replaced with f.e. async web call to the server to confirm login.

Comment: Yes, you beat me to it while I was editing. Anything that is awaitable will do the trick and you won't need to start a task.